# Is it possible to make a marquee using picture?

Tags: scroll, marquee

Im trying to make a layout with a picture which appears to be moving like a marquee? Is it possible? Please help.. thanks...

Comment: What language? What platform (cross-platform, Windows, *nix, etc.)? Do you want to implement this in Flash/Actionscript, HTML/CSS/Javascript, Java, C, C++, C#, Python, etc.? Is this for a website, a video, some kind of interactive medium, etc? Do you want it to scroll vertically, horizontally, diagonally, or what? How big is this picture? What is the nature of this layout? Have you even tried doing this? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you tried doing some prior research on your own? Have you tried seeing how others did it? Seriously, you question is sorely lacking in details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```
<marquee scrolldelay="100" bgcolor="grey">
    <img src="img.png"/>
</marquee>
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3c6NL/1/)

**Edit:** it works in all modern browers, and even in ie6,7,8

Answer (score 0):

if you just want a moving image....this should suffice :

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"><img src="/pix/smile.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="smile" /></marquee>
```

Useful [link](http://www.mountaindragon.com/html/marquee.htm)